# Java BufferedReader while loop out of bounds exception

Tags: java, bufferedreader, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using BufferedReader to read data from a text file. The variable "reg" is the fourth entry in the string of data that I am trying to access.

I am getting the exception: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"

Here is my code:

```
package calctest;

import static calctest.CalcTest.reg;
import java.io.*;

public class CalcTest {

    static Integer reg, prov;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

String readFile = "M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\JAVA for NEMS\\EORModule\\NEMSEORDB.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String delim = "[ ]+";

    try {        
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String [] reservoir = line.split(delim);

            reg = Integer.parseInt(reservoir[3]);

            System.out.println(reg);

         }
         }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         }catch (IOException e) {

       }    

     }

  }
```

Comment: Remove br.readLine() which is at top of while(...)

Comment: ^^ What he said. That first line of the file is being thrown out when you call readLine() and don't do anything with it.

Comment: Consider adding a `System.out.println("line="+ line);` as the first line in the loop so you can see the line you are looking at.

Comment: Also remember to close your bufferedreader after you're done reading (perhaps in a finally block) to avoid leaks.

Comment: I tried removing that line, but I still get the same error

Comment: Can you put for(String s : reservoir) System.out.println(s) before reg = ... and post what that outputs?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at calctest.CalcTest.main(CalcTest.java:73)

Comment: I see that the database I am using has one line with the "@" symbol recorded on the third line of the database. Is there a way to navigate to the symbol and begin reading from that position?

Answer (score 2):

Your error has nothing to do with the reading. The error is that reservoir (sometimes) has a length less than 4.

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String [] reservoir = line.split(delim);

        for(String s : reservoir)
            System.out.println(s);  //Post what this outputs for debugging purposes

        if (resivoir.length > 3)
            reg = Integer.parseInt(reservoir[3]);
        else
            reg = ... //do something else...

        System.out.println(reg);

 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure `br.ready()` is correct. `ready()` can return false if there's no data in the buffer and the underlying `Reader` returns `false` from `ready()`, which can happen whenever the underlying `Reader` can't guarantee that the next read will not block. That isn't necessarily only going to happen at end of file.

Comment: fair enough. The more important part is the length check of the array. I'll change my answer

Answer (score 0):

The exception is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.Oracle docs says:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

The error->java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 means you are trying to access index 3.

The line which is accessing index 3 is

```
   reg = Integer.parseInt(reservoir[3]);
```

please put a check like following

```
 if (resivoir.length > 3)
            reg = Integer.parseInt(reservoir[3]);
        else
            //there must be some error or do something else
```