# SQlite: Query to find the total of all values in a column?

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, cursor

I am trying to add a functionality to my app that allows the user to view the average of their scores from all the game sessions they have played.

In order to do so I need to find the total of all values in a column within the Database.

This is my current attempt:

**Query Method:**

```
/**
     * Method that gives the the total of all
     * Average Meditation levels in the DB
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getTotalOfAllMedLevels(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT SUM(avgmeditation) FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;


        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        //Add in the movetofirst etc here? see SO
        c.moveToFirst(); 
        c.getInt(0);

        return c;



    }
```

**Attempting to implement it, setting cursor equal to its return value in textview:**

public void displayAverageOfAllMedValues() {

```
    //Setting cursor to return value of the method?
    Cursor c = db.getTotalOfAllMedLevels();

     if( c != null && c.moveToFirst() )
        {

             avgMed.setText("" + c.getInt( 0 ) );

        }

}
```

This just gives me the answer `0`at the minute which I know isn't correct, What am I doing wrong?

**The table structure (for reference):**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

    // Database Name
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MeditationDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_SESSION = "sessionid";
    private static final String COL_GAMETITLE = "game";
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_MED = "avgmeditation";
    private static final String COL_MAX = "maxmeditation";
    private static final String COL_AVGATT = "avgattention";
    private static final String COL_MAXATT = "maxattention";
    private static final String COL_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "date";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //VERY IMPORTANT: ALWAYS CHECK THAT THERE ARE SPACES AND COMMAS IN CORRECT PLACE IN CODE BELOW:

        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "(" + COL_SESSION
                + " STRING PRIMARY KEY, " + COL_GAMETITLE + " STRING, "  + COL_NAME + " STRING, " + COL_MED + " INTEGER, "
                 + COL_MAX + " INTEGER, " + COL_AVGATT + " INTEGER, " + COL_MAXATT + " INTEGER, "  + COL_SCORE +  " INTEGER, " + COL_DATE + " STRING " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);

    }
```

**EDIT:**

When trying to implement the following code I am getting a NullPointerException related to the displayAverageOfAllAttValues() method.

Updated Activity:

```
public class thirdActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView count;
    TextView avgMed;
    TextView avgAtt;

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);

        initialiseVars();

        displayAllResults();



    }

    public void initialiseVars(){

        count= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSummary1);
        avgMed= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSummary2);
        avgAtt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSummary3);

    }

    //Facade method that then calls all the rest
    public void displayAllResults(){

        displayNumberofGamesPlayed();

        displayAverageOfAllMedValues();

        displayAverageOfAllAttValues();
    }

    public void displayNumberofGamesPlayed(){

        //show how many games have been played
        int totalGamesPlayed = db.getTotalGamesPlayed();
        count.setText("games played " + totalGamesPlayed);

    }

    public void displayAverageOfAllMedValues() {

        //Setting cursor to return value of the method?
        int i = db.getTotalOfAllAvgMedLevels();
                 avgMed.setText("Total of med" + i );

    }

    public void displayAverageOfAllAttValues() {

        //Setting cursor to return value of the method?
        int i = db.getTotalOfAllAvgAttLevels();
                 avgAtt.setText("Total of att" + i );

    }



}
```

displayAverageOfAllAttValues() method in databaseHelper:

```
public int getTotalOfAllAvgAttLevels(){


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT SUM(avgattention) FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    c.moveToFirst(); 
    int i=c.getInt(0);

    return i;

    }
```

**Logcat error report:**

```
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219): Process: com.example.brianapp, PID: 10219
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brianapp/com.example.brianapp.thirdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2140)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:625)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at com.example.brianapp.thirdActivity.displayAverageOfAllAttValues(thirdActivity.java:78)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at com.example.brianapp.thirdActivity.displayAllResults(thirdActivity.java:55)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at com.example.brianapp.thirdActivity.onCreate(thirdActivity.java:34)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
08-08 00:36:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10219):    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Try to call your class DatabaseHelper  instead of SQLiteDatabase when you get the getWritableDatabase(). And you also should close the connection, doing this db.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some error in code.See if doing the following changes work

```
public int getTotalOfAllMedLevels(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT SUM(avgmeditation) FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    //Add in the movetofirst etc here? see SO
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    int i=c.getInt(0);

    return i;



}

public void displayAverageOfAllMedValues() {

//Setting cursor to return value of the method?
int i = db.getTotalOfAllMedLevels();
         avgMed.setText("" +i );
}
```

Comment: Can you please see my edit, I am getting an error when I try to add another almost identical method!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the following method:

```
public void displayAverageOfAllAttValues() {

        //Setting cursor to return value of the method?
        int i = db.getTotalOfAllAvgAttLevels();
                 avgAtt.setText("Total of att" + i );

    }
```

put log for db and avgAtt variable and check which one is null and fix the issue accordingly.

refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191648/java-bufferedreader-while-loop-out-of-bounds-exception/25192333#25192333) for the approach to be followed for debugging issues